# Convert Java-method to Objective-C method

Tags: java, ios, objective-c

I need to convert this Java method with time tables into Objective-C.

What would be the easiest (or the best) way to do this?

```
public static String GetMonth(String month){    
    String january = "01;06:40;08:37;12:15;13:35;15:51;17:41&"+
    "02;06:40;08:37;12:15;13:36;15:52;17:42&"+
    "03;06:40;08:36;12:16;13:37;15:53;17:43&"+
    "04;06:40;08:36;12:16;13:38;15:54;17:44&";
    String february = "01;06:13;08:01;12:24;14:19;16:46;18:27&"+
    "02;06:12;07:59;12:25;14:21;16:48;18:29&"+
    "03;06:10;07:57;12:25;14:22;16:50;18:31&"+
    "04;06:09;07:55;12:25;14:24;16:52;18:33&";
    if (month.toLowerCase().equals("january")) return january;
    else if (month.toLowerCase().equals("february")) return february;
    else return null;
}
```

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Start by following the Java Naming Conventions first: `getMonth`.

Comment: That's it???  Just rewrite it.  What's the problem???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
+ (NSString *) GetMonth: (NSString *) month{
    NSString* january = @"01;06:40;08:37;12:15;13:35;15:51;17:41&02;06:40;08:37;12:15;13:36;15:52;17:42&03;06:40;08:36;12:16;13:37;15:53;17:43&04;06:40;08:36;12:16;13:38;15:54;17:44&";
    NSString* february = @"01;06:13;08:01;12:24;14:19;16:46;18:27&02;06:12;07:59;12:25;14:21;16:48;18:29&03;06:10;07:57;12:25;14:22;16:50;18:31&04;06:09;07:55;12:25;14:24;16:52;18:33&";
    if ([[month lowercaseString] isEqualToString:@"january"]) return january;
    else if ([month lowercaseString] isEqualToString:@"february"]) return february;
    else return Nil;
}
```

Comment: According to the Java code it's a `static` method, so change the method type identifier from `-` to `+`.

Comment: yeah sorry, did not notice that. fixed it.

Comment: Why didn't you use `caseInsensitiveCompare`, to avoid creating a new lower case `month` value?

Comment: Yeah that could have been done, but the java implementation of the method converts the `month` to lower case and so I just did the same.

Answer (score 1):

Try with following formation:

For publicly use, 
define method in **.h file.**

```
+( NSString *) GetMonth:(NSString *) month;
```

And put body of method in **.m file.**

```
+( NSString *) GetMonth:(NSString *) month
{
    .
    .
    .
    //your code;         
}
```

Comment: Also, remember to change the method type identifier from `-` to `+`, it's a `static` method.